# A torsor equivalent for a ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory

Reading [John Baez's essay on torsors](http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/torsors.html), I was quite intrigued with the last section which states:

> "Finally, one more remark for people who want to go further. Near the beginning of this essay, I said "as soon as we pick units of temperature, temperatures are elements of an R-torsor". We need to pick units of temperature to know what it means to "add 1" to a temperature. So, where should we think of temperatures a living before we pick units? We should think of them as living on a line whose symmetries include not just translations but also dilations - in other words, the "stretchings" or "squashings" that result from a change of units. Picking an origin reduces the symmetry group to just dilations - and indeed, there's a distinguished choice of origin, namely absolutely zero. Picking units reduces the symmetry group to just translations, giving us an R-torsor - and indeed, there's a distinguished choice of units, namely Planck units. Picking both lets us think of temperatures as real numbers. This combination of translations and dilations arises because R is not just a group, but a ring. So, there's a more sophisticated concept than that of "torsor" allowing both translations and dilations whenever you start with a ring."

So, what is a generalization of a torsor for a ring?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A free [module](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Module_(mathematics)) of rank one. ${}{}{}$

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have just one question. Suppose we were to study a plane. Before adding any structure on it, it is an affine plane. The affine space does not have the notion of origin (if it did, it would be a vector space), but does it have a notion of units (a 1)? If so, is the unit (1) defined via metric or in some other way? How should I think of an affine plane without units defined on it?

Comment: @Little: let's stick to the one-dimensional case. A choice of units for a free module of rank one is a choice of basis for the module.